# I need to get an array instead of an object from a firestore collection

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material2

I am starting to use Angular material with cloud-firestore and I have the following problem with the origin of the data and the datasource for the table. The problem is that the query to firestore returns an object with indexes and MatTableDataSource needs an array, and I can't convert the object that returns the query to an array.
I have tried to use loops and the .map operator to fill an empty array but I always create an array of objects with an index, not a simple array of objects.

this is my data base:

[Collection that I'm querying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PBMg.png)

My service:

```js
findpagosCliente(pagosId: number[]) {
    const col = this.afs.collection<Cliente>('pagoscliente')
    const queries = pagosId.map(el => col.doc(el.toString()).valueChanges());
    return combineLatest(...queries);    
}
```

My component:

```js
inicializarTablaPagos() {
this.clienteService.findpagosCliente(this.clienteSeleccionado.facturacion.pagos).subscribe((pagos) => {   
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(pagos); 
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.showClientData = true;
    })
}
```

MatTableDataSource wait for an array but angularfire2 query send me back and object like this:
[object from firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gog4Y.png)

I have tried a lot of loops and operators to try to create a new simple array but they all end up generating a new array like the one in the previous image. For example this:

```js
this.clienteService.findpagosCliente(this.clienteSeleccionado.facturacion.pagos)
      .subscribe((pagos) => {   
        let arraytemp = [];     
        pagos.map(element => {
          arraytemp.push(element)
        })
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(arraytemp); 
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.showClientData = true;
      })
```

I know I am doing something wrong, and that it will be very obvious, but right now I am unable to see it.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The result that you get is already an array. Just look at the notation in your image: `[{...}, {...}]`
Squared brackets are always an indicator for an array.

Comment: The problem was in the definition of the columns in the table, they did not match the reference and the name, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Are you saying about the field names?